# Regarding Microchip XC8 compiler's registers and bits definitions

Tags: pic, c, microchip, compiler, xc8

I'm going to take a random 8-bit Microchip microcontroller: [PIC16F887](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/41291f.pdf).

Let's have a look at how the XC8 compiler (and the HI-TECH PICC, for that matter) is defining a register (SFR) and its coresponding bits in the header file of the device (`/opt/microchip/xc8/v1.31/include/pic16f887.h`):

```
extern volatile unsigned char           PORTB               @ 0x006;
```

So `PORTB` SFR is defined as an 8-bit volatile variable with the absolute address 0x006, as per the datasheet.

I'm having problems understanding the definition of a single bit (bit 1, for example) corresponding to PORTB:

```
extern volatile __bit                   RB1                 @ (((unsigned) &PORTB)*8) + 1;
```

Why do they multiply the PORTB address by 8?

**EDIT:**

I also looked for an explanation in the compiler's manual and found pretty much the same answers that [Spehro](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/35530/spehro-pefhany) [gave me](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/123119/4906). I should have consulted the manual before asking here:

> When defining absolute bit variables (see Section 5.4.2.1 “Bit Data
>   Types and Variables”), the address specified must be a bit address.
>   A bit address is obtained by mul- tiplying the desired byte address by
>   8, then adding the bit offset within that bit.
>
> So, for example, to
>   place a bit variable called mode at bit position #2 at byte address
>   0x50, use the following: bit mode @ 0x282; If you wish to place a bit
>   variable over an existing object (typically this will be an SFR
>   variable or another absolute variable) then you can use the symbol of
>   that object, as in the following example which places flag at bit
>   position #3 in the char variable MOT_STATUS:
>
> `bit flag @ ((unsigned) &MOT_STATUS)*8 + 3;`

Comment: In this .h, it is completely different: http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/courses/CStudio/SDCC%20Compiler/sdcc-src-2.8.0/sdcc-src-2.8.0/sdcc/device/include/pic/pic16f887.h

Comment: @Swanand Yeah, they use unions and structs to define the register's bits. The Microchip compilers do that as well, besides the definitions I mentioned..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit addressing uses the lower 3 bits of the address to point to the bit within a byte.

So the bit is number (RB1 & 0x07) or 1 in your example, the byte address is (RB1 >> 3), or 0x06 in your example.

Comment: I don't think I understand your explanation. Take the expression from the bit definition: `@ (((unsigned) &PORTB)*8) + 1;` Let's evaluate this expression: &PORTB = 0x06. 0x06 * 8 = 0x30 (0b00110000). 0x30 + 1 = 0x31 (0b00110001). How is 0x31 the address of bit 1 of PORTB?

Comment: The compiler knows what type if object (bit) the address points to, and treats it differently from a byte address. Try looking at the emitted machine code for very simple bit set/clear statements.